# Random number multiplication Game

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game to multiply 2 random numbers  and give 4 options including the right answer to choose from. My problem is I can't figure out how to include the right answer for the multiplication problem mixed in with the random generated answers

```
// button to start and reset the game

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    display.textContent = equation;
    displayStyle();
    for(var i=0;i<text.length; i++){
        text[i].textContent=answer[i];
        btn.textContent="Play Again!"
    }
});

// push the random numbers in an array to be looped unto the screen

function answers(n){
    var correct = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i<n;i++){
        correct.push(randomAnswers());
    }
    return correct;
}

// the random 2 numbers that are multiply and seen by the user

function multply(){
    var x =Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var y =Math.floor(Math.random()*11);

    return x+"x"+y+"= ";
}

function displayStyle(){
    display.style.fontSize = '5rem';
    display.style.border="1px white solid";
    display.style.marginLeft="34%";
    display.paddingRight="5%";
}
```

the random answers that the user will choose from, i want the right answer to be generated in the mix or the two functions to communicate so the logics can validate when the right answer is selected

```
function randomAnswers(){
    var a =Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var b =Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    return a*b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `multply` is picking two new random numbers, not any of the numbers that were used to create the choices.

The `randomAnswers()` function should include `a` and `b` in the returned value. Then you can pick a random element from the `answers` array, display the numbers that were multiplied, and test if the answer matches the product.

```js
let correctAnswer;

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const answer = answers(4);
  const chosen = answer[Math.floor(answer.length * Math.random())];
  display.textContent = multiply(chosen.a, chosen.b);
  correctAnswer = chosen.answer;
  for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    text[i].textContent = answer[i].answer;
  }
  btn.textContent = "Play Again!"
});

// push the random numbers in an array to be looped unto the screen

function answers(n) {
  var correct = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    correct.push(randomAnswers());
  }
  return correct;
}

// the random 2 numbers that are multiply and seen by the user

function multply(x, y) {
  return x + "x" + y + "= ";
}

function randomAnswers() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  return {
    a,
    b,
    answer: a * b
  };
}
```